# i've styled my hr tag but it doesn't work, what should i do?

Tags: html, css, hover, background-color

when I enter the details of hr tag in my style.css, it doesn't show me the result!
HTML:

`<hr class="hr1">`

I wanna have a hr tag which has some details like color, hover, text-align and I wanna change its width too.

this is what I wrote in CSS:

```
.hr1{
    background-color: violet;
    width: 79%;
    text-align: center;

}
.hr1:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

but the only thing that I can see in my html page, is a gray 79% line in center of the page!
Not a line with the color and hover I specified!.

Comment: An `hr` is *only* composed of borders... instead of background color, change the border color.

Comment: as @Paulie_D said, just change the .hr1{border: 2px solid  violet;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `<hr>` by default doesn't have height. You can define which `height` you want, and can remove the `border` all together.

```css
.hr1 {
  background-color: violet;
  width: 79%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 2px;
  border: 0;
}

.hr1:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
text
<hr class="hr1">
another
```